# Form of a matrix in a basis where some of the basis vectors are eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was studying linear algebra from Treil's LADW, and this is a problem from the text that I couldn't come up with an answer for. Why does a matrix like this have this form?

Let $\vec{v}_1 , \vec{v}_2 , . . . , \vec{v}_n$ be a basis in a vector space $V$. Assume also that the first $k$ vectors $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2 , . . . , \vec{v}_k$ of the basis are eigenvectors of an operator A, corresponding to an eigenvalue $λ$ (i.e. that $A\vec{v}_j = \lambda\vec{v}_j , j = 1, 2, . . . , k)$.
Show that in this basis the matrix of the operator $A$ has block triangular form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda I_k & ∗ \\
0 & B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $I_k$ is $k \times k$ identity matrix and $B$ is some $(n − k) \times (n − k)$ matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remember how we write the matrix $A$ in terms of the given basis.

In general, given a basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ (I am suppressing the $\vec{}$ in the vectors), then we apply $A$ in each $v_j$ and write the result as a linear combination of this basis. So, if
$$
Av_j=a_{1j}v_1+\ldots+a_{nj}v_j,
$$
then the $j$-th column of the matrix $A$ will have the entries $a_{1j},\ldots,a_{nj}$.

For your particular case, we have
\begin{align*}
Av_1&=\lambda v_1+0v_2+\ldots+0v_n,\\
Av_2&=0v_1 + \lambda v_2+\ldots+0v_n,\\
&\phantom{123456}\vdots\\
Av_k&=0v_1+\ldots+\lambda v_k+0v_{k+1}+\ldots+0v_n.
\end{align*}
Then the first $k$ columns have the stated form. For the remaining vectors, it does not really matter what will be:
\begin{align*}
Av_{k+1}&=a_{1,k+1}v_1+\ldots+a_{n,k+1}v_n,\\
&\phantom{1234}\vdots\\
Av_n&=a_{1,n}v_1+\ldots+a_{n,n}v_n,
\end{align*}
Hence the author just represented by a star $*$ and a $(n-k)\times(n-k)$ matrix $B$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I got confused because the author refers to both the original matrix A, and the new matrix B (in the given basis) as A in a subsequent chapter (I think it was the one about diagonalization), which made me go back and try this problem.